# Menu category item. Shorten permalink word

Tags: wordpress

I can't seem to find where or what file does the 'category' word gets parsed/passed to create the link for categories on Wordpress. Basically, what I want to accomplish is to shorten the 'category' word to 'c' much like:

```
somewebsite.com/category/category_name
```

to
    somewebsite.com/c/category_name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can achive it by change slug of category from admin:

```
Setting >> Permalink
```

Under optional section,

There is Category base section

In there textbox where you can mention slug whatever you want for URL for category URL.

Comment: Thank you. I can't even begin to think how did I miss that.